# SQL Server Spatial Data

Tags: sql-server, spatial

Thanks in advance for any insight. I am new to using the spatial functions in SQL Server. I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the basic correct approach to solving a problem I have.

I am working with a client that monitors gas wells that are accessible from waterways. In a given day, a boat travels from point A to point B along the river. I have that "route" as a series of Lat/Long values that can be plotted on a map. I'm thinking that this would be used as a LineString in SQL Server.

I also have a list of known wells, along with their Lat/Long positions. I would like to store these records in a database, and index the Lat/Long with a spatial index of some sort. I'm not 100% sure how to index the table correctly, but it would contain the columns Lat/Long/WellName/Owner, etc.

The feature needs to do the following: Given the Lat/Long of the route the boat takes in a given day (the LineString and all of it's points), find all of the wells that are within 2000 feet of that line. The workers will get off of the boat and go to the well to perform maintenance on them. Each day they will work a different section of the river.

Again, I'm looking for directional advice on what the Wells table (tblWells) needs to be, and also create a stored procedure that accepts the Lat/Long of the line points as a nvarchar(MAX) input parameter. For now, it only needs to return all of the wells that are within 2000 feet of any point on the line.

Sincere thanks to anyone who takes the time to help.

Kindest regards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'd need a table of wells:

```
create table dbo.Wells (
   WellId int identity not null,
   Name varchar(50) not null,
   Owner varchar(50) not null,
   Location geography not null
)
```

And then a procedure to search for wells within a certain distance of a given path:

```
create procedure dbo.FindWells
( 
  @Path geography,
  @Distance float
) as
begin

   declare @buffer geography = @Path.STBuffer(@Distance);

   select WellId
   from dbo.Wells
   where @buffer.STContains(Location);
)
```

If you really want to pass your path as a varchar, go for it; just make transforming it into a geography instance with `geography::STLineFromText` or something like that.

As for the indexing on the table, create a spatial index on the Location column. Play around with the resolution, but I'm guessing that given your use case, the first three resolutions will be low with the last being high. Play around with it, though.

Comment: Sorry, but it would not let me respond fully with a comment. I had to add an answer to add a follow-up question. This is bang on; thank you.